# Update Blob in Google Storage using Python SDK

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-api-python-client

I want to update a Blob saved in Google Cloud Storage, the Blob is inside a bucket and I am own. I would like update its content which is only text plain. I have tested a lof of times but I can't get it. My code is:

```
from google.cloud import storage, exceptions
BUCKET_NAME = 'my-bucket-name'
BLOB_NAME = 'auditoria.txt'
PROJECT_NAME = 'my-project-name'
storage_cliente = storage.Client() # I have a environment variable in windows for auth

def get_bucket_object():
"""Get a bucket"""
    bucket = None
    try:
        bucket = storage_cliente.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
    except exceptions.NotFound:
        bucket = storage_cliente.create_bucket(bucket_or_name=BUCKET_NAME, project=PROJECT_NAME, location='us-east1')
    return bucket

def get_file_log():
    """Retorna un objeto de tipo BLOB presente en un bucket"""
    try:
        bucket = get_bucket_object()
        blob = bucket.get_blob(BLOB_NAME)
        if (blob == None):
            raise(Exception(f'El blob con nombre {BLOB_NAME} no existe, por favor creelo'))
        return blob
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Ha ocurrido un error: {e}")

def write_log(msg):
    blob = get_file_log()
    print(blob.name)
    content_blob = blob.download_as_string().decode("utf-8")
    blob_txt = content_blob + '\n' + msg
    print(blob_txt)
    blob.upload_from_string(blob_txt)
    print("Blob actualizado correctamente")


write_log(
    'WARNING Esta es una prueba mas real'
)
```

I get this error:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 POST https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/auditorias_servihuella_cali/o?uploadType=multipart: ('Request fa
iled with status code', 400, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>)
```

So I don't know, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I get an answer:

You can't update an object (Blob) created prevoiusly in a bucket, because the objects in google cloud are immutables. This is a fragment of google documentation:

> "Objects are immutable, which means that an uploaded object cannot change throughout its storage lifetime. An object's storage lifetime is the time between successful object creation (upload) and successful object deletion. In practice, this means that you cannot make incremental changes to objects, such as append operations or truncate operations."

More details here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms#immutability

Comment: You can certainly upload new content to completely replace an existing object, giving it a new version.  You just can modify an object and have the version stay the same.  You have to read on where those docs say: "*However, it is possible to replace objects that are stored in Cloud Storage, and doing so happens atomically*"

Comment: @DougStevenson Do you have some example of code about you mention above?